# Broadcast live iPhone video feed iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, streaming

Is there any way to take the video feed from the camera of an iPhone and broadcast it to a local server (or remote if necessary)?  It does not need to save it to the server, just to be able to access it.  Sort of like a web cam app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at Technical Q&A QA1702: [How to capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1702.html), which explains how to capture frames from the iPhone camera.

Answer (score 1):

this will help as well..
http://www.benjaminloulier.com/articles/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera

in the sample code, the raw data from the camera is covered to an UIImage.
My problem now is how to send the data to a server to be converted to a video stream